# Why do my mappers appear to repeat the "last merge-pass" many times?

Tags: hadoop

In the task logs of my mappers, I'm seeing behavior like this, which is confusing me:

```
INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 6 sorted segments
INFO org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor
INFO org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor
INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 6 segments left of total size: 38872249 bytes
INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 6 sorted segments
INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 6 segments left of total size: 38636106 bytes
INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 6 sorted segments
INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 6 segments left of total size: 39490573 bytes
INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 6 sorted segments
....
repeat 20+ times
....
INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 6 segments left of total size: 37234005 bytes
INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task:attempt_201209251414_0326_m_000052_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_201209251414_0326_m_000052_0' done.\
```

How is it that I'm having 25+ "last" merge passes? This process takes forever, so I'm trying to figure out if I've configured something incorrectly.

Comment: Looks to me like a bug. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm working with a fully distributed installation of Hadoop 1.0.3. The job this is happening during is part of rowsimilarity from Mahout 0.7 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Is there documentation somewhere saying "if your mappers are too slow, you'll repeat the 'last merge-pass' 25 times"? It seems like a weird behavior.

Comment: How many reducers do you have assigned, and what's the value of `io.sort.factor` and `io.sort.mb` in your job.xml?